# How to write a script for google sheets condionaiol formatting? / Keep CFormatting range locked

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I'm using the conditional formatting in google sheets and I'm encountering a problem in which every time I do any kind of action like copy/paste the CF range changes and I end up with a whole mess of colored cells.

Is there a way to lock the range of the CF ? if not, could someone suggest a script I can use to have my condiontions static and applied at least everytime i use the sheet?

They are all this kind: if cell 'x' is not blank than color the whole row 'y'.

cheers,

Comment: Can you post a mock-up of your sheet? Moreover, what have you tried in order to accomplish this? @Ofer

Answer (score 0):

To avoid conditional formatting from getting copied when you paste a cell, use **Edit > Paste special > Paste values only** (`Control+Shift+V`).